# Error when connecting to database with PostgreSQL and dblink_connect

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have a strange problem with PostgreSQL and `dblink`.
I have a remote PostgreSQL installation on amazon RDS 9.5.2 and a local PostgreSQL installation on Windows 10.

I am trying to transfer data from the local installation to the remote installation using `dblink`. I am connected to the remote database with a query window opened from pgAdmin III.

When connecting to the default `postgres` database I am successful:

```
select dblink_connect('dbname=postgres host=localhost user=postgres password=xxx');
```

However when I try to connect to any other database I get an error:

```
select dblink_connect('dbname=gti host=localhost user=postgres password=xxx');
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  FATAL:  database "gti" does not exist

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not establish connection
SQL state: 08001
Detail: FATAL:  database "gti" does not exist
```

I have changed ownership to the `postgres` user for the database.

But I am at my wits end what else to try.

Edited. A screenshot from PgAdmin showing the databases both remote and local:
[pgAdmin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2KmZ.jpg)

Edited 2: I ran `select * from pg_database;` as requested:
[Result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otOba.jpg)

Edited 3: I set up a new PostgreSQL installation on another machine on our local network. Connected to Amazon and got exactly the same error.

If I connect from PostgreSQL on this new pc to PostgreSQL on my pc in pgAdmin, open a query window and `dblink_connect` from there to the local instance I get no error. So it seems to be either an error when connecting to a database outside our network, or just Amazon specifically.

Edited 4: If I add another user to my Local PostgreSQL instance and grant it superuser access, I cannot connect to my local instance from the amazon query window using `dblink`. I can however connect to my local instance using this new user from the other PostgreSQL on the local network.

Comment: Looks like gti does not exist on your localhost. Maybe you must switch to the remote hostname.

Comment: No. It definitely exists. I tried all my local DBs. I cannot connect to anyone except the automatically created postgres. Even created the specific one specifically during the test. If I do the reverse and connect from local to remote, I can reach all DBs.

Comment: You are able to connect but the source you connect does not have the required database. If gti exists and postgres is the owner, you must reach this database and this message will not show up. Do you have multiple versions of postgresql running on localhost, on which port does the gti database run?

Comment: Not true on both accounts. I've edited my post to show a pgAdmin screenshot.

Comment: Could you post the result of SELECT * FROM pg_database;

Comment: I've updated my post. Thanks a lot for the help!